# Terminate promise given a socket disconnects

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, cancellation

I have an [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/) website that utilizes [socket.io](https://socket.io/). For each user (socket) that connects, a function is called that can take a long time to resolve.

server.js

```js
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = new Server(server);

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  console.log(`${socket.id}: socket connected`);

  console.log(`${socket.id}: computation started`);
  await longRunningTask();
  console.log(`${socket.id}: computation completed`);


  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log(`${socket.id}: socket disconnected`);

    // TODO: Check if `longRunningTask` has resolved. If it has not, cancel it
  });
});
```

This is the current flow of the program given a user disconnects before the `longRunningTask` resolves:

*User visits website* (they are assigned socket.id `tCzH`)

```sh
tCzH: socket connected
tCzH: computation started
```

*User disconnects*

```sh
tCzH: socket disconnected
```

*Some time passes*

```sh
tCzH: computation completed
```

---

My goal is to terminate the `longRunningTask` immediately given the socket is disconnected. What would be the best approach?

Comment: You should start by listening for the `disconnect` event *before* waiting for the `longRunningTask` to finish :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is impossible to terminate the execution of a function from outside its' scope in Javascript. Even if you wrap your `longRunningTask` in a Promise and reject that Promise manually, it will not prevent the rest of its stack from execution.

Implementation of `longRunningTask` has to be modified so it is dependent on a global variable that is in the outer scope, and once this variable becomes for example false it should return or break itself from within.